# How to prevent an igraph plot for an undirected graph object changing each time it is plotted?

Tags: r, igraph

In the following code in `igraph`, I have plotted an undirected graph with edges and nodes:

```
g <- make_undirected_graph(edges = c(1,2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3), n = 10)
plot(g)
```

It creates a different plot each time I call `plot(g)`, even if I fix `g` ahead of time. Is there a way to prevent this? I tried looking at the `layout` parameter but it doesn't seem to work for the undirected graph functions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, layout does work.  Try this.

```
LO = layout_nicely(g)
plot(g, layout=LO)
```

You should be able to run the plot statement many times with the same result. 
Just run the plot statement,  don't rerun the layout statement.

Alternatively, you could just set the random seed each time you plot.

```
set.seed(1234)
plot(g)
```

If you run *BOTH* of these lines repeatedly, you should get the same result.